# call ebay api of bulk_migrate_listing then Error 2003

Tags: ebay-api

I tried to call https://api.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/bulk_migrate_listing, then response code is 2003

My request is :

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "listingId": "160009220563"
        }
    ]
}
```

Response body like this :

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "errorId": 2003,
            "domain": "ACCESS",
            "category": "APPLICATION",
            "message": "Internal error",
            "longMessage": "There was a problem with an eBay internal system or process. Contact eBay developer support for assistance",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "reason",
                    "value": "Failed to transform underlying error response, see logs."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I say this as a comment, because it is an unworthy answer, but an ebay basic subscription includes 600 listings per month. So if you only have 600 items in store, delete, start over, then don't list anything for the rest of the month. I hope a better answer comes up, but meanwhile, that's what I'm doing.